# SELECT Specific Row After Processing Whole Statement In MySQL

Tags: mysql

Here are my example results:

```
+------+-----------------+--------+
| rank | nick            | amount |
+------+-----------------+--------+
|    1 | 038112125147518 | 0.2000 |
|    2 | 0tosan          | 0.2000 |
|    3 | 13unnyeater     | 0.2000 |
+------+-----------------+--------+
```

Which was returned by SET / SELECT statement:

```
SET @rank=0; SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, nick, amount FROM points;
```

What is the most efficient way to return the row matching:

```
nick='13unnyeater'
```

...AFTER the 'rank' column was tabulated using the above? The result I would expect would be:

```
+------+-----------------+--------+
| rank | nick            | amount |
+------+-----------------+--------+
|    3 | 13unnyeater     | 0.2000 |
+------+-----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Why would that row have a rank of 3?  All have the same amount?  What is distinguishing them?

Comment: rank without ORDER BY? Weird.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unclear and no feedback is given after 3 weeks.